# aws lambda - handling code when dynamodb capacity is exceeded

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

My lambda function contains some code that includes queries to dynamodb. Once a query is executed, the lambda continues with the rest of the code, which is based on the result of that query. What happens if I exceed the capacity limit of the dynamodb? I can push the query to SQS and process it later, but then I will not be able to continue the execution of the lambda. Another solution would be to retry each query that fails, but if the dynamodb is extremely busy, my lambda might exceed the 5 minute limit. Seems like a lose-lose situation. What would you do?

Answer (score 0):

The most fault-tolerant solution would be to decouple the querying and the processing of the results.

1. Instead of processing results immediately, write the results to another SQS queue and send an SNS notification.
2. Move the processing to a second Lambda function. This new function can be triggered by the SNS notification. It can read the results queue and process any pending messages.
3. Modify the original function to queue any failed queries for later.